# Angular2 Primeng datatable performance is low

Tags: angular, primeng

Am using Primeng `Datatable` component for my CURD application.
I used primeng's `Autocomplete` and `Dropdown` component in `p-column`.

**Faced two issues as follows**,

> 1. `Performance is very low when i have >= 20 rows in datatable`. 
>    - Even the autocomplete component click event itself takes 5-6
>      Seconds to appear cursor inside the component.
> 2. The suggestion list of autocomplete and dropdown is not visible. 
>    - If set [style]="{'overflow':'visible'}" in p-column and
>      ui-datatable-scrollable-body datatable scroll bar is not working.
>
>    - If i override css "{'position':'fixed'}" in dropdown component (.ui-dropdown-items-wrapper then the suggestion list not appearing in
>        right place.

Can any one suggest an idea to do it ?

Am using Primeng: 1.0.0, Angular:2.1.2, node: 6.6.0, os: win32 x64

Please see this picture
http://www.screencast.com/t/FmgoMg7E

Answer (score 3):

With primeng 2.0-RC.1 there are lots of enhancements on performance issues maybe you can try to upgrade your primeng version.

Comment: Yes, performance of having `p-dropdown` in `p-column` is improved in `primeng 2.0-RC.1`. but still it is low for `p-autocomplete` component. Please have a look at my comments here http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=49116

Comment: Hi Mertcan, any updates for this issue ?
Still struggling with autocomplete component in datatable. :-(

Comment: It has some improvements after RC1 but there will be some performance upgrades in future releases.